# Why does TypeMock MockManager need a Verify() and Init() and MOQ not

Tags: c#, moq, typemock

I use MOQ alot and never had the need to call a `Init()` in my `SetupForEachTest` method and a `Verify()` in my `CleanUpForEachTest` method.

Why does MOQ need that not ?

Where is the technical difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of Typemock Isolator you don't need to call Init or Verify because you can use the automatic initialization and cleanup attributes in your test fixture.

In fact, if you're using the Arrange Act Assert syntax for Typemock (which looks like Moq syntax) then you shouldn't be doing anything at all with the MockManager.

Check out the Typemock web site for documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Because Moq doesn't use **record-reply-verify** model.

http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/whats-wrong-with-the-recordreplyverify-model-for-mocking-frameworks/